# Unity Facebook Login not using iOS integrated Facebook

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Unity 4.6b19 + Unity Facebook 6.0 SDK + iOS8. When I log into facebook with no Facebook App installed but I am logged into Facebook via the iOS settings it still forces me to login using the browser. Should it not default to the native iOS Facebook integration?

It uses the Facebook app correctly so everything seems setup from my end.

My Facebook app is not live (if this makes a difference).

Comment: Looks like If i change `[self.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView`
to `[self.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent` it will sort it

Comment: it in FbUnityInterface.mm